# inserting a row from one table to another in mysql on clicking a hyperlink

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a list of users registered on a website and when the admin clicks to approve, it must be inserted into another table called `login`. I have the code , its not throwing any exception or any error but it's simply not transferring row data from one table to another.

Below is my servlet:

And my DAO:

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into login(id,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,Dateofbirth,Age,Address,Country,State,city,PinCode,EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo)select * from register where id=?");
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
```

Please someone help me fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: No thanks needed, I am only the last stop on the edit train.  Someone else (click the 'edited' link for details) helped you out first.

Comment: Can you check if your id is getting the query ? Which error or exception are you getting ? Try only that query direct against your database and confirm if it works.

Comment: no error or exception is thrown.... its just not moved from one table to another

Comment: `approve.clientApprove(id);` if yOu are suspecting here .. Have you checked With `try and catch ` block  ?  And Are you sure that Query is working on your database And `register ` table is having the same number of columns of `login` table ?

Comment: sorry am a newie can u just tell me how to check whether a query is working on the database by executing it singly??

Comment: Yes Exexute that query on PL/sql developer out of the java I mean

Comment: yes its executing but whole table is getting inserted into another table not a particular row so i added that id parameter to the method... i doubt that servlet is not fetching the id....           'Client client = new Client();                                     int id=client.getId();'      I doubt this line of code

Comment: Then post `client.getId()` code

Comment: sorry i didnt get u??

Comment: `public int getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }`

Comment: `client.getId()` is returning no value .. Then what is that Method is it a `getter method of id parameter` or a custom method ?

Comment: Its a getter method of id parameter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47813/discussion-between-user3222718-and-looser)

Answer (score 1):

Okay if it Is `getter of parameter Id` the declaration of that variable should not be like that 
I dont know much about spring MVC but getter declaration should be like this

```
 private int id;/ * This is the parameter you are expecting from Front End 
 public int getId()//*This is the getter of that parameter.
 {
    return id;   
 }
 public void setId(int id)//Setter of ID parameter which sets the ID value to the local ID parameter
 {  
      this.id = id;

  }
```

``

In your code you are creating new object for `client` class and calling the `getter` method for parameter. What I mean here is `id` parameter setted in different object of `client` class and you are calling that method with newly created `getId()` in some other class. 
  I dont know how it works in `spring` usually in MVC frameworks `Every fomr will be related to a bean` In that bean you will have `setter` and `getters` for fields in form .. 
 So I recommend you to try to use the exact object of particular form there you can get the value of `id` parameter

Comment: **ya its the same thing what i have done....i forgot to post the id declaration on the top... like  **                                `int id;
 public int getId()
 {
    return id;   
 }
 public void setId(int id)
 {  
      this.id = id;

  }`

Comment: ya am partially able to understand but what do you mean by exact object of particular form?? you mean to say that object of particular bean of a particular form??

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm  In this example .. `Student.java` is `bean` In controller class the calling of `getters of parameters` please refer

Comment: Though i couldnt arrive at the conclusion perfectly i learnt a lot from yo posts thanks for being so humble @looser

Comment: You mean new problem related to this one ?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871656/inserting-a-row-from-one-table-to-another-in-mysql-on-clicking-a-hyperlink) This is how i solved my problem.... @looser